# Junit code generator tool/framework for REST API based on spring mvc

Tags: java, junit, code-generation, spring-restcontroller

i have a Spring MVC based project that needs Junit creation for many classes. I tried junit-tool, randoop both outputs looks good for basic java projects and regression test cases (incase of randoop), it requires lot of rework.  However there is no tool i could find that can generate Junit for **Rest controllers**, along with mock objects for other class calls, mockmvc etc... A decent skeleton would be good enough to move forward.
Note: it does not have any other frameworks like swagger to leverage.

Answer (score 2):

**Telosys** (http://www.telosys.org/) could be the tool you're looking for.

It's a code generator working with customizable templates (Velocity templates). You can create your own templates. Telosys is available as a simple Command Line Interface tool (https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-cli/wiki) and as an Eclipse Plugin (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools). Everything is Open Source (tool and templates).

The customizable templates are available on GitHub (https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3).

Some templates examples are available for JUnit test cases. Examples :

https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java7-persistence-jpa-T300/tree/master/test

https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java7-persistence-spring-data-jpa/tree/master/test